# Text to speech service gone and key binding for it not functioning in Yosemite?

Tags: keyboard, macos, services, text-to-speech

Up until Yosemite I have always had a text to speech service menu option and have been able to readily use a command key combination to trigger the reading of selected text in just about any application.

Under `System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Services`, looking under the Text subsection, there is nothing there to enable for text-to-speech.  Further, `System Preferences -> Dictation & Speech -> Text to Speech` has "Speak selected text when the key is pressed" enabled and a key combination set and this key command simply doesn't work (and yes, even when I change this to another set of keys).

Neither of these have functioned properly for me since my initial usage of Yosemite this past summer and I am curious as to whether others have found a solution.

Does anyone:

1. Know how one can make TTS appear in the service menu again and
2. Have you figured out a way to make the key combination work
   reliably in applications?

Comment: The default is alt+esc ? is that not working? which Voice have you selected ?

Comment: It is not.  Alex and Tom.

Comment: does it play in test mode ?

Comment: @Buscar웃 yes it is working in the actual dialogue box in System Preferences, but not in applications.

Comment: Strange, so when you Change the keys does it speak them after you pressed the new keys ?

Comment: It does not.  I cannot trigger speech via the keys.  I have seen it work on a very rare occasion, but the situation is not reproducible.  I was hopeful that someone might have some insights on how to reset these altogether via the shell so as to wipe any kinds of plists or db config entries or such that may be causing this.